# Finding a formula for the $n^{\text{th}}$ term in a series solution to $y''+y'+e^{-x}y=0,y(0)=3,y'(0)=5$

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations

I am tasked to find a formula for the $n^{\text{th}}$ term in a series solution to $y''+y'+e^{-x}y=0$ subject to initial conditions $y(0)=3,y'(0)=5$.

If $y$ is a solution to this DE and $D=\frac{d}{dx}$ it isn't too hard to see by taking successive derivatives that $$\Big[D^{n+2}+D^{n+1}+e^{-x}(D-1)^n\Big]y=0 \text{ for all } n\geq 0$$ Since $(D-1)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}{n\choose k}D^k$ can write this as $$\Bigg[D^{n+2}+D^{n+1}+e^{-x}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}{n\choose k}D^k\Bigg]y=0$$ If we evaluate this as $x=0$ and rearrange terms we can say $$y^{(n+2)}(0)=-\Bigg[y^{(n+1)}(0)+\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}{n \choose k}y^{(k)}(0)\Bigg]$$ Is there any chance of finding a general formula for $y^{(n)}(0)$ in terms of $n$? I also considered writing $y$ as $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nt^n$ and $e^{-t}$ as $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-t)^n}{n!}$ and solving for the coefficients this way, but I wasn't about to spend a majority of my day collecting coefficients. Thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest computing first few values of $y^{(n)}(0)$ in your notation and see if the sequence tells you something from the OEIS database. If not, there is probably not a closed form.

Comment: also,  the standard technique of handling linear recurrence will require you to solve:
$$x^{n+2} + x^{n+1} + \sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}{n \choose k}x^k = 0 \iff x^{n+2}+x^{n+1} + (x-1)^n = 0.$$
which probably do not have their roots in closed form.

Comment: @dezdichado. Amazing problem !

Comment: @dezdichado are you sure we can solve the linear recurrence relation in the method you suggest? My understanding is that your suggested technique only works if the recurrence relation has constant coefficients. This recurrence relation doesn't appear to have constant coefficients because of the $(-1)^{n-k}{n \choose k}$ term (which depends on $k$)

Comment: yeah I don't think this has a closed form since like you said the coefficients are dependent  on $k,n.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Computing the first $a_n$
$$\left\{3,5,-4,1,\frac{3}{8},-\frac{17}{40},\frac{131}{720},-\frac
   {197}{5040},-\frac{3}{1120},\cdots\right\}$$ does not leave much hope.

But,
$$y=e^{-x/2}\,z \quad \implies \quad z''+\left(e^{-x}-\frac{1}{4}\right) z=0$$ let a little hope expanding it as a series of $t=e^{-x/2}$ since the new differential equation looks like a Bessel equation.

So, let $e^{-x}=t^2$ and solve
$$z''+\left(t^2-\frac{1}{4}\right) z=0\quad \text{with} \quad z(0)=3\quad \quad z'(0)=\frac {13}2$$

Comment: Very slick, thank you